# Any gcloud Command Fails With ImportError: No module named __future__ Mac

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I'm on MacOS. My default python is a virtual environment created from a brew install of Python 2.7.15. My `PATH` is set up so that the venv is the default `python` and `python2.7`. I had some issues installing gcloud that [have been resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54446718/mac-gcloud-install-importerror-no-module-named-future) and I have successfully installed gcloud.

However, any time I try to run any `gcloud` command I still get the same ImportError I was seeing upon install.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path_to_gcloudsdk/google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py", line 20, in <module>
    from __future__ import absolute_import
ImportError: No module named __future__
```

**Additional Info Per Comment Requests:**

Output when I enter my default python's interpreter and run `import sys; print(sys.path)`:

```
[
    ''
    '/path_to_virtual_env/lib/python27.zip'
    '/path_to_virtual_env/lib/python2.7'
    '/path_to_virtual_env/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin'
    '/path_to_virtual_env/lib/python2.7/plat-mac'
    '/path_to_virtual_env/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages'
    '/path_to_virtual_env/lib/python2.7/lib-tk'
    '/path_to_virtual_env/lib/python2.7/lib-old'
    '/path_to_virtual_env/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload'
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7'
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin'
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk'
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac'
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages'
    '/path_to_virtual_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
]
```

Comment: What's the result of `import sys; print(sys.path)`?

Comment: @user2357112 I added the requested info

Comment: @chepner they are the first group of imports in `gcloud.py`

Comment: Does ``head `which gcloud` ``reveal anything about how the command starts Python?

Comment: Can you import *anything* from the standard library? I'm not sure it's possible for you to be getting an error importing `__future__` without your Python interpreter being completely messed up.

Comment: @Blckknght: simple: run a virtualenv Python with `-S`, so `site` is not imported. Then try to use `from __future__` imports. A virtualenv Python can’t really function without the custom virtualenv `site` module.

Answer (score 2):

Ended up being the same issue I was running into with the install. The `google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud` shell script used the `-S` flag to run `gcloud.py`.

I edited the shell script so that it does not add any python args and now it all works fine.

Thanks again @Martijn Pieters for bumping me in the right direction

Comment: I scoured high and low for the past 45 minutes looking for the quick fix, and this helped me! The other question points only to install.sh but I did not know that the fix would involve going into `gcloud`